# Python GUI Library for Windows/Gnome

Tags: python, user-interface, cross-platform

I need to create a desktop app that will work with Windows and Gnome(Ubuntu).  I would like to use Python to do this.  The GUI part of the app will be a single form with a message area and a couple of buttons.

The list of GUI's for Python seems overwhelming.  I am looking for something simple if possible, the main requirements is it must work with Gnome(2.26 and up) and Windows XP/Vista/7.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426718/what-cross-platform-gui-libraries-are-simple-lightweight-and-have-minimal-depen

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses.  I wish I could vote up, but it looks like I need to build my reputation.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to check out wxPython. It's a mature project and should work on Windows
and Linux (Gnome).

Comment: I'll try this one first since it seems like its popular.  Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: If you ask me, wxPython is hands down the best one, it didnt become that popular without reason. But its far from easy, quite overwhelming to say the least. If youre looking for power, go with wxPython, but if youre looking for something easy/simple, I think youre better of with something else.

Answer (score 3):

[PyGTK](http://www.pygtk.org/) is a very popular GUI toolkit, but usually quite a bit easier to use on Linux than on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the [extensive list of GUI libs](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming) for Python? For something simple I recommend, as does the list, [EasyGUI](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Looks like this fits the bill.  I'll have to look into this if wxPython is too cumbersome.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro) or [PySide](http://www.pyside.org). Both are Python wrappers to Qt. PyQt is the original wrapper; PySide is a new project by [Qt Development Frameworks](http://qt.nokia.com)/Nokia that has pretty much the same aims as PyQt, just with different licensing. PyQt is more mature, but licensing is more restrictive; PySide is quite new (in alpha/beta) but with more liberal licensing. However, for real information on licensing, check their site and preferably with a lawyer if it concerns you.

Comment: +1 Although Qt is not native to Gnome (which is GTK based), from a development perspective it is much easier and more intuitive to work with. I have used both PyGTK and PyQt, and PyQt is the clear winner. Even more so when it comes to Windows -- getting GTK to work on Windows can be a pain. And---back on Linux---there's no real problem with running a Qt app within a GTK-based desktop environment.